# Always mount everything with read/write permissions (Fedora)

Tags: fedora, permissions, storage

In fedora, if I plug in a usb drive, I would like to have all read and write permissions by default.  It doesn't matter what format, just anything plugged in is default read and write.

I would also like to have read write available on any storage device at all, including hard drives.  Default behavior: read and write on anything.

How do I make every storage device connected to my computer read/write by default.

Comment: Every Linux distribution I have ever seen will mount (almost) all storage devices read/write unless explicitly told otherwise. Can you plug in a USB drive , run the `mount` command, and post the line matching the device?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora does/should mount everything is can to the best of its abilities.  If one is having issues, it's likely caused by the format of the drive.  Most drive support exists in the linux kernel, not the OS level.

Check this table for support:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#OS_support